# Copying file from SFTP to Azure Data Lake Gen2

Tags: azure, powershell, etl, sftp, azure-data-factory

So my problem is quite stupid but I cannot find a way to resolve it. I have one 15 GB file on external SFTP server that I need to copy to my data lake. The thing is that column delimiter is a comma and I have some nested lists as well. So when I am trying to use ADF copy activity, the result looks like that:
[image]

And most of my data is gone(as nested structures get cut on the first occurence of comma). So maybe I could ignore delimiter. I have tried to set pipe as a delimiter just to get this whole dataset as one column but this doesnt work either.

[image]

Powershell? I have tried different scripts that used to work with smaller files and I am getting an error every time.
[image]

I have even tried to upload it manually via Azure Storage Explorer but it fails as well after some time. I am not really sure how to make it work at this point.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Are you working on the data in flight or just trying to copy the file as-is from SFTP to ADLS?

Comment: What activity do you use to copy the data? Because with a copy activity no data should be lost at all. It just copies binaries and does not look whats inside the file.

Comment: @Repcak csv source csv sink, basic ADF copy activity, no additional transformations.That's what I have expected but I am left with 11 GB(data lake) out of my 45 GB(SFTP).